# Unavoidable retain cycle using UISearchBar as UITableView's header view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, uisearchbar

I ran into this issue as I was building out a basic UI that makes use of a `UISearchController` and it's `UISearchBar` member. My tableView is a weak IBOutlet, and like the Apple Docs demonstrate, I set its tableHeaderView property to be the search bar member.

```
//Snippet from viewDidLoad
UISearchController* searchController = [self createSearchController];
UISearchBar* searchBar = searchController.searchBar;
searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; //The assignment in question

[NetworkStuff makeCall:^(Response *response) {
    //handle success
    searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //local variables
    searchController.active = YES;
    ...
} failure:^(Response *response) {
    //handle failure
    ...
}];
```

When I pop the view off of the stack, its dealloc method never gets called, even if I set the tableHeaderView to nil in `viewWillDisappear:`. The only line I need to comment out to see dealloc called is that initial assignment.

Anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening?

EDIT:

Found some interesting behavior. Also per the Apple Docs I set the controller's `definesPresentationContext` variable to `YES`. Commenting that out while leaving the tableViewHeader assignment in fixed the retain cycle, even if I didn't nil out the tableViewHeader. However, setting `definesPresentationContext` in `viewDidLoad` and clearing it in `viewWillDisappear` re-introduces the retain cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled upon this answer:
[UISearchController retain issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141155/uisearchcontroller-retain-issue)

The solution appears to be dismissing the UISearchController explicitly in `viewDidDisappear:` (note, I could not get this to work in `viewWillDisappear:`). Since that code is in swift, I'll just transcribe it here for Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    if (!self.presentingViewController) {
        [self.searchController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

As the original answer points out, the check for `self.presentingViewController`'s non-existence is helpful in the case where another view controller was pushed on top of the view, since we'd be coming back to the page. In all likelihood, we only want to dismiss the searchController when we're popping the view controller that contains it.